# Retaining uploaded file (FileField) when form is not valid

Tags: django

Given a Model with a required field called `number` and a [ClearableFileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput) FileField called `upload_file`:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    upload_file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In my view, on POST, if the form `is_valid` then I can populate the *clearable* part of the FileField when returning to the same page.

```
def example_view(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_instance = form.save()
            form = ExampleForm(instance=form_instance)
            # or alternatively, for just the upload file field
            form = ExampleForm(initial={'upload_file': form_instance.upload_file})
        else:
            form_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            form = ExampleForm(initial={'upload_file': form_instance.upload_file})
            # unfortunately, this also does not work:
            form = ExampleForm(initial={'upload_file': form.fields['upload_file']})
    else:
        form = ExampleForm()
return render_to_response('enterrecords/example.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Django ClearableFileInput]

However, if the form is not valid (see first else case), I can not `form.save(commit=False)` and therefore cannot populate the *clearable* part of the FileField.

The `form.save(commit=False)` gives the following error:

```
ValueError at /en/myapp/example/
The ExampleModel could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

**Is there a workaround for this problem?**

For completeness...

ModelForm

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
```

Template

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'eg' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="next" value="Next" />Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Unless the file field itself is not validating, you can extract correctly validated data from `form.cleaned_data` dictionary. You don't need to create an (unsaved) instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `form.clean_xxx` with `xxx` being the field to clean in your `form`. It is called *before* the call to `is_valid()` of your view.

Here's a sample of what I do when I get an Excel file in my form (my `UploadedFileHandler` class is useless here, it's just to show you the principle).

The idea is that, even if the form is not valid, the Excel file is **always** saved and thus I keep a trace of what happened:

```
def clean_excel_file(self):
    uploaded_file = self.files.get('excel_file')
    if uploaded_file:
        try:
            nom = UploadedFileHandler.generate_filename(
                splitext(basename(uploaded_file.name))[1])
            dst = UploadedFileHandler.get_url(nom, 'imports/excel/')

            # sauver le fichier
            dst_full = UploadedFileHandler.full_filename(dst)
            UploadedFileHandler.make_dir(dst_full)
            UploadedFileHandler.save(uploaded_file, dst_full)

            retour = ExcelFile.objects.create(
                # description = nom de fichier sans l'extension :
                description=path.splitext(basename(str(uploaded_file)))[0],
                fichier_origine=uploaded_file,
                excel_file=dst)
            retour.save()
            return retour
        except IOError:
            self.errors['excel_file'] = ErrorList([_("Unknown file type")])
    return None
```